# How to make right-side triangle in CSS ribbon menu?

Tags: css, menu, ribbon

As you'll see from this CodePen, I am nearly complete with this ribbon menu. However, I cannot (for the life of me) figure out how to add the right-side triangle using CSS. When I attempt to add the following code, it adds a big margin underneath the navigation menu:

```
#menu-nav:after {
 border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) #008000 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) transparent;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 22px 25px 0px 0px;
 height: 0px;
 left: -10px;
 width: 0px;
```

}

I know that those aren't the right border widths, but it should still show something more than a big bottom margin, right? My CodePen is here: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/fryec1135/pen/wdrel)

The only thing I think may be causing this is something to do with how the blocks are positioned. I have the `#menu-nav:before, #menu-nav:after` positioned relative. I'm still a little new, so any help would be appreciated.

FYI - this is the original tutorial that I was following: http://css3.wikidot.com/blog:wrap-around-ribbons-with-css

Comment: Here is an updated CodePen where the menu-nav:before and menu-nav:after are positioned absolute: http://codepen.io/fryec1135/pen/dgoEH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply the parent must have a width and position rule, and children position: absolute

Here is a working example

EDIT: I checked your code, and you have visibility set to hidden, add visibility: visible to :after pseudo-element and it should work

[Codepen: Ribbons with pseudo elements](http://codepen.io/mallendeo/pen/EgCKi)

```
.menu{
  width: 100%;
  height: 4em;
  background: #333;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 2em;
  left: -2em;
}

.menu:after,
.menu:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 100%;
  border-top: 1em solid #999;
  border-right: 1em solid transparent;
  border-left: 1em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1em solid transparent;
}
.menu:before {
  left: 0;
  border-right: 1em solid #999;
}
.menu:after {
  right: 0;
  border-left: 1em solid #999;
}
```

Comment: You're a life saver! How could you tell that visibility was set to hidden? I didn't see that anywhere. It's working perfectly now. That had me seriously scratching my head, lol

Comment: Can you help me with one last thing? For some reason my triangle is flipped the wrong way. What do I need to do to get the right triangle facing the right direction? Thanks for all of your help. You rock! http://codepen.io/fryec1135/pen/dgoEH

Comment: @BrandonFrye I saw it with the inspector, select #menu-nav, and check :after and :before in styles ;)

Comment: I ended up using this, but I'm not sure it's the "best" way to do it: '-moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2)'

Comment: @BrandonFrye change the border color order, border-color: #008000 transparent transparent transparent;

Comment: Boy, I've got so much to learn. But I love learning new things, so it all works out! Hah. I switched the order and it works perfectly. You've been a huge help. I appreciate it so much.